# Is there a bash script for finding a specific character between two given expressions?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have a 3-step problem: I need to

1. find all occurrences of the character `:` in a latex file **but only when it is in a `\ref{}` or in a `\label{}`,** in which there can be other characters. Example: `The system's total energy (\ref{eq:E}).`
2. replace those `:` with `_`. Example becomes: `The system's total energy (\ref{eq_E}).`
3. do this for all such occurrences of `:` in references or labels, in about 100 files.

I've never done this before. I've worked out that I can use regular expressions to find complex occurrences. I can find either `\ref{` or `\label{` with `(\\ref\{|\\label\{)`, but I can't put it in a lookbehind because it is not fixed width. My other problem with lookbehind and lookahead is that I can only match everything between my assertions, not specific characters (from what I've understood).

I've also worked out that I can use sed for find and replace. I was planning on using a regular expression as my sed "find". Does that make sense?

And finally, I'm not sure how to go about looping on all my files (which have ordered names). Can I do an if or while loop in a bash script?

I know that my questions are all over the place, as I said, never done this before and there is a mountain of documentation I'm only beginning to tackle. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The biggest problem you'll find with lookarounds is that they aren't implemented in any regex flavour that `sed` can use. `grep` can use them with the `-P`(CRE) flag but that's about all for the usual linux tools

Comment: Can there are be more than one `:` to be replaced in the same label/ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command which relies on capturing groups to extract the different parts of a ref or label containing a colon to replace it with the equivalent using an underscore :

```
sed -E 's/\\(ref|label)\{([^:]*):([^}]*)}/\\\1\{\2_\3}/g'
```

The expression captures the whole ref or label tag, matching the tag name in the first capturing group, the part that precedes the colon in the second capturing group and the part that follows the colon in the third capturing group. The replacement pattern uses references to these capturing groups and can be read as `\<tagName>{<before colon>_<after colon>}`.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/J5lAHm).

Note that it would be prefereable to use a parser that understands the latex format, the regex is likely to fail for some edge cases.

> And finally, I'm not sure how to go about looping on all my files (which have ordered names). Can I do an if or while loop in a bash script?

`sed` accepts a list of files as parameter and will apply its command on all of them. The list of files can be produced by the expansion of a [glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html), e.g. `sed 'sedCommand' /your/directory/*.txt` which would work on all file of `/your/directory/` whose name end in `.txt`.

In this case you will likely want to use `sed`'s `-i` "in place" flag which asks `sed` to direcly write its result in the target file rather than on its standard output. The flag can be followed by a suffix if you want a backup of the original, for instance `sed -i.bak 'command' file.txt` will have `file.txt` contain the result and `file.txt.bak` the original.

Comment: @NinaE no, but you could use `/your/directory/**.txt` with the globstar [shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) or use `find` as follows : `find /your/directory/ -name '*.txt' -exec sed -iE 's/\\(ref|label)\{([^:]*):([^}]*)}/\\\1\{\2_\3}/g' {} +`